# What is this express variable is doing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oop

I recently started learning JS and I am a basic programming background previously but always stuck on OOPs concepts.

So here we are importing I think the express module by writing the required (express). But I don't understand why we are storing this in a variable.

Likewise then storing express() in app variable then using app variable to do some stuff.

I mean how's this is working? What is What in this code block? Please explain in detail.

Thanks in advance.

```
const express = require('express')
const { createReadStream }  = require('fs')

const app  = express()

app.get('/' , (req,res) => {
    createReadStream('index.html').pipe(res)
})
```

Comment: Why do you store something in a variable? To use it more than once without the necessary overhead of creating another instance of it.

Comment: if I was in your position, I would not learn express JS without learning some fundamental programming in OOPS and also JavaScript. This is basic express JS and you are literally asking us to explain a chapter to you. Strongly recommend you try some basic JS. for example, go here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 1: You import the express node module that you installed with `npm i express` and store it in a constant (const).

Line 2: You import the function or variable `createReadStream` from the file system module of node.js (fs module) and make it available for use in this file.

Line 3 you assign the `express()` function from the express module above to a constant called `app`, so you now have everything express related available to you on the `app` constant.

Line 4-5: You use the `get` method from the express() function you have stored in the `app` constant, and create a route for the base url of your app / (e.g. domain.com/ or localhost:8000/). If you request something from the server you send a GET request. If you send some data use POST or PUT, for example, the express() function in `app` have these methods for you to use, too (app.post for example).

When Postman or a regular user with a browser hits this part of your domain (route) with a GET request, the arrow function on line 4 (req, res) => kicks in. It takes in the request (req) and the result (res) parameters so you can use those inside of the function if you wish. On the req parameter you have available whatever is in the body the user sends in from a form, for example. In your case your route streams back a html file to the user via http in order to display it in the user's browser.